# Java DeepCopy Iterator without consuming it

Tags: java, iterator

How can I copy my iterator to another one without consuming it ? Or at least if I can reset the index back to first element after I can consume it. 
I am looking for something like below, where it should still print the values after copying it;

```
Iterator iter2=copy(iter1);

while(iter1.hasNext())
{
    System.out.println(iter1.next()); // Should print this, even after copy
}
```

Comment: Why deep copy an iterator?

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please tell us about the problem you're trying to solve, not about the solution you've attempted. An iterator is a throwaway object that can be constructed time and again, so deep-copying it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I am trying to log the values somewhere from iterator.

Comment: @Pratik no the function of an Interator is to be an only forward way of iterating through values. You could though do something tricky by wrapping the iterator with a custom class which calls the wrapped iterator and logs the values as the next method is called. But this is a bit hacky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contract of an `Iterator` is to be an "only forward" way of iterating through a series of objects.

As mentioned in your comment, you are trying to log the values of an `Iterator`, yet still the use the Iterator elsewhere.

You could though do something tricky by wrapping the `Iterator` with a custom class which calls the wrapped `Iterator` and logs the values as the `next` method is called.

A bit hacky. Not recommended in general but could be useful in a debugging situation.

You would construct this `WrappedIterator` using the original `Iterator` as parameter and then pass the `WrappedIterator` to the code which consumes it.

```
public class WrappedIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    private Iterator<T> iterator;

    public WrappedIterator(Iterator<T> iterator) {
        this.iterator = iterator;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        this.iterator.remove();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return this.iterator.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        T next = iterator.next();
        System.out.println(next);
        return next;
    }
}
```